# Boost Fibonacci Heap

Tags: c++, boost, fibonacci-heap

I was looking at the code of the boost Fibonacci heap, and in many places, I saw a variable called `_id` of type `ID` (part of the template) being used like this:`get(_id, d)`, where `d` is of type `T&`, where `T` is part of the template. What is the purpose of this, and what would the equivalent of this be with only the default c++ standard libraries.

Here is the code for the fibonacci heap:

```
 void push(const T& d) {
        ++_n;
        size_type v = get(_id, d);
        _key[v] = d;
        _p[v] = nil();
        _degree[v] = 0;
        _mark[v] = false;
        _child[v] = nil();
        if (_root == nil()) {
            _root = _left[v] = _right[v] = v;
            //std::cout << "root added" << std::endl;
        } else {
            size_type u = _left[_root];
            _left[v] = u;
            _right[v] = _root;
            _left[_root] = _right[u] = v;
            if (_compare(d, _key[_root]))
                _root = v;
            //std::cout << "non-root node added" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should give an actual example (with line number), because your wording is totally unclear and we don't all have time to go read boost source code to find out

Comment: I have made it clearer.